# How can i use extends correctly? php

Tags: php, oop

Summary.php

```
<?php namespace interfaces\summary;

use \interfaces\id\id;

class Summary extends \interfaces\id { // This is line 7
 // ... code
}
```

---

id.php

```
<?php namespace interfaces\id;

class id {
 // ... code
}


Fatal error: Class 'interfaces\Id' not found in H:\ngnx\nginx-1.9.9\html\server\interfaces\userSummary.php on line 7
```

I don't know what is the error there. i need to include the file?
(both files are in the same folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `id` is in the namespace `interfaces\id`. This means that its full name is `\interfaces\id\id`.

You will want to changes your extends line to either:

```
class Summary extends \interfaces\id\id
```

or, because you already have the `use \interfaces\id\id` statement the line before,

```
class Summary extends id
```

Comment: @DanielMartínMuñoz Accept this